# Delete files from TFS that aren't in my local workspace

Tags: tfs

I've got a copy of boost (v1.57) checked in to TFS, and want to upgrade to the latest version of boost (v1.60). So, I've checked out all the files and copied over the new version of boost. I could add any new files and check this in.

But, I want to remove any files that were in v1.57 and which are no longer in v1.60.

How can I achieve this? Ideally I need a way to add pending deletes for any files that no longer exist on my local file system.

When I've done this in the past I've used a diff tool to compare the two versions of boost, then I've manually deleted missing items from TFS. But, I'd really like an automatic way.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a solution.

1. Install TFS PowerTools.
2. Get Latest on all the files, but don't check them out.
3. Delete all the local files (not via TFS, use Explorer)
4. Copy the new Boost files to where the old ones were.
5. From the command prompt run:

   `tfpt online /deletes /adds /diff /recursive`
6. Check in

All the necessary changes pop up in a dialog. Click "Pend Changes" and wait for quite a while for the adds/edits/deletes to be added to your pending changes list in TFS.